# 5 Design Patterns in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I have a project coming up and we have to create a game using JavaFX and we have to use 5 design patterns. So far in all our homeworks we have only been using one. How do I go about using 5 design pattern in one program?

EDIT: I understand there are many design patterns Java has, but my question is: How do I use multiple patterns in one program? So far in class we have only been using one design pattern per game and I was just wondering how do I go about using 5 instead of one?

I hope I made it a bit clear!

Comment: It's javaFX, so you can probably just check of the observer pattern it's hard not to use something from the [`javafx.beans.property` package.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a great description of many Java design patterns described over in [this tutorials point page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/).  If you are instead wondering how to implement one of these design patterns, or when they might be useful, could you perhaps make your question a bit more specific/targeted?  There are MANY design patterns, so I don't know that anyone would be able to cover all of it in a single question (though, maybe someone will prove me wrong :) )

Comment: Thank you :) I have made my question clearer. Hopefully it makes sense!